# Error when I try to set a variable with output of command as I configure set -euo pipefail in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, set, output

I tried to check if Kubernetes cluster namespace exists and handle the case if it does not. I initialize my bash script with **set -euo pipefail** in order to handle errors.

The context is I need to implement the script when **my_ns** does not exist.

I stored the output of the **kubectl get ns my_ns** command (as it returns error message) into a bash variable but the script exits:

**The point is I don't understand why when I use environment variable with export command it works**:

I stored the output of the **kubectl get ns my_ns** command into a bash variable:

```
checknsoutput=$(kubectl get ns my_ns 2>&1)
```

I tried with export and it works

```
export checknsoutput=$(kubectl get ns my_ns 2>&1)
```

I enabled the "debug" mode thanks to the following command in order to have more verbosity:

```
set -x
```

This is the snippet of the logs for the script with the export command:

```
++ kubectl get ns toto
+ export 'checknsoutput=Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "toto" not found'
+ checknsoutput='Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "toto" not found'
+ echo 'RESULLT: Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "toto" not found'
```

This is the snippet of the logs for the script with a basic variable:

```
++ kubectl get ns toto
+ checknsoutput='Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "toto" not found'
```

If I correctly understand the *kubectl get ns my_ns* returned 1 and it catches by the script and exists before the initialization of the value *checknsoutput*.

I expect to understand why it does not work with variable whereas it does with export variable.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export` is a command with its own exit code. In general it exits 0 unless you tell it to export an invalid shell variable, so it will mask the exit code of the command substitution and prevent `set -e` from aborting the script.

If you *want* the script to exit on the command failure, you need to perform the assignment and export steps separately.

```
checknsoutput=$(kubectl get ns my_ns 2>&1)
export checknsoutput
```

See [BashPitfalls 27](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#local_var.3D.24.28cmd.29).

Comment: thanks for your answer. Are we agree your code snippet failed if an error occures during the kubectl command? It happened when I included it into my code.
I wonder if it is possible to check after the assigment of kubectl output command to checknsoutput variable if this one contains the substring "not found"? I would like to check that in order to decide if I create the specific namespace or not without pass the command directly into the if condition?

Comment: See [BashFAQ/105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for tips. Most people would recommend not using `set -e` at all because it has a lot of complex rules, but if you must use it and you want to ignore a command failure then you have to do something like `checknsoutput=$(kubectl get ns my_ns 2>&1 || true)` to ignore the error so that you can inspect the value of `checknsoutput` later.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was just to understand why this behaviour occurs. I finally test directly in an if condition whether the output of my command is equal to "my_ns" like this:  if [[ $(kubectl get ns | grep "my_ns" | awk  '{print $1}') == "my_ns" ]]; then echo "my_ns already exists else echo "my_ns des not exists" fi